# How to turn off Startapp test ads mode

Tags: flutter, ads, startapp

I have no idea how can I turn off startapp  test mode function on my app, I emailed the customer service and they replied me that I should turn off  test mode function

Comment: What are ads service do you using? If it is AdMob, try to build your app in a release mode.

Comment: @fartem no I am using startApp ads service, you have any idea on what i can do about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using [startapp](https://pub.dev/packages/startapp) package - test ads automatically disabled in `release` mode ([issue on GitHub](https://github.com/vdung7/startapp_flutter_plugin/issues/14)).